# Standard method for handling not found (404) errors in all kind of web server

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, nginx

I use `Apache` as default web server in my projects and usually use `mod_rewrite` rules with `.htaccess` file in order to navigate virtual urls like: `http://example.com/en/page/parameters...` to `index.php` file and everything works fine.

But i'm trying to improve my projects compatibility in order to work with every web servers such as `Nginx`, `Litespeed`, `lighttpd`, `IIS` and so on. but obviously `.htaccess` file is not supporting by all of them. I'm looking for a standard method or a permanent solution to handle not founded errors by running a php file instead to simulate `mod_write` someway.

if such standard method doesn't exist, what is best substituent way to handle rewrite rules like beyond codes for most common web servers such as above examples:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
Options -Indexes
```

Answer (score 1):

That Task would require you to follow certain design principles.

First of all you would need to have some kind of [Front-Controller](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Front_Controller_pattern) which handles all incoming requests (to prettify URI's you'd still need to set up some kind of URL-Rewriting which is again webserver dependent).

Next you would need some kind of routing layer which dispatches a URI to a certain action. Everything that is not supposed to be dispatched by your router should throw a 404.

That's about it. Here is a very basic example which outlines the parts that have to be done. But be careful: *In real world applications both, the Front-Controller, and the Router are some of the most important parts of an application, so consider to not reinvent the wheel.*

```
<?php

$routes = [
    'home' => 'home.php',
    'about-us' => 'aboutus.php'
];

if( ! array_key_exists( $_GET['page'], $routes ) )
{
    // The 'page' get parameter has no value that matches with the 
    // router so respond with a 404
    header('HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found');
    echo "I'm a 404 and I'm handled via PHP";
}
else
{
    echo $routes[ $_GET['page'] ];
}
```

*(URL Rewriting not included since it's not part of the question)*

Comment: Thanx for your tips. I use my own framework based on MVC Architecture that have a central Front-Controller to parse URIs. but it works on actual URI ($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']) and not $_GET. but problem is working by all kine web servers.

Comment: Yeah the actual method of parsing the Request URL is not important at all :) just wanted to point you into the right direction